# Make Regex Match Whitespaces in Java

Tags: java, regex

How can I make this regex match white spaces? Currently, it can only match the following:

```
abcdatcsdotuniversitydotedu
```

I would like it to mach the following:

```
abcd at cs dot university dot edu
```

This is the Regex:

```
([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.\\-_]*)\\s[ ]?(at)[ ]*([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-_(dot)]*[ ]?(dot)[ ]*[A-Za-z]+)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` matches a white-space character and when this is used in a java string you need to escape the `\` so it would be `\\s`. If you want to match zero-or-more white-space then use `\\s*`.

This will match a single domain and TLD:

```
([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.\\-_]*)\\s*(at)\\s*([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-_()]*\\s*(dot)\\s*[A-Za-z]+)
```

However, you are trying to match multiple levels of sub-domains so you need to wrap the domain part of the regular expression `([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-_()]*\\s*(dot)\\s*` in `()+` to get one-or-more of them:

```
([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.\\-_]*)\\s*(at)\\s*(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-_()]*\\s*(dot)\\s*)+[A-Za-z]+)
                                       ^                                        ^^
```

Something like this:

```
public class RegexpMatch {
    static Pattern Regex = Pattern.compile(
            "([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.\\-_]*)\\s*(at)\\s*(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-_()]*\\s*(dot)\\s*)+[A-Za-z]+)"
        );

    public static void main( final String[] args ){
        final String[] tests = {
                "abcdatcsdotuniversitydotedu",
                "abcd at cs dot university dot edu"
        };

        for ( final String test : tests )
            System.out.println( test + " - "  + ( Regex.matcher( test ).matches() ? "Match" : "No Match" ) );
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
abcdatcsdotuniversitydotedu - Match
abcd at cs dot university dot edu - Match
```

Comment: @ZachariaMwangi Please define "doesn't work"... the example code I've given successfully matches your input data.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumericWithWhiteSpace(String text) {
        return text != null && text.matches("^[\\p{L}\\p{N}ın\\s]*$");
    }
```

> \p{L} matches a single code point in the category "letter".
>
> \p{N} matches any kind of numeric character in any script.

I am using this code.